# how to get the intersection of two JSON arrays using jq

Tags: arrays, json, intersection, jq

Given arrays X and Y (preferably both as inputs, but otherwise, with one as input and the other hardcoded), how can I use jq to output the array containing all elements common to both? e.g. what is a value of f such that

```
echo '[1,2,3,4]' | jq 'f([2,4,6,8,10])'
```

would output

```
[2,4]
```

?

I've tried the following:

```
map(select(in([2,4,6,8,10])))  --> outputs [1,2,3,4]
select(map(in([2,4,6,8,10])))  --> outputs [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple and quite fast (but somewhat naive) filter that probably does essentially what you want can be defined as follows:

```
   # x and y are arrays
   def intersection(x;y):
     ( (x|unique) + (y|unique) | sort) as $sorted
     | reduce range(1; $sorted|length) as $i
         ([]; if $sorted[$i] == $sorted[$i-1] then . + [$sorted[$i]] else . end) ;
```

If x is provided as input on STDIN, and y is provided in some other way (e.g. `def y: ...`), then you could use this as: `intersection(.;y)`

Other ways to provide two distinct arrays as input include:

- using the `--slurp` option
- using `--arg a v` (or `--argjson a v` if available in your jq)

Here's a simpler but slower def that's nevertheless quite fast in practice:

```
    def i(x;y):
       if (y|length) == 0 then []
       else (x|unique) as $x
       | $x - ($x - y)
       end ;
```

Here's a standalone filter for finding the intersection of arbitrarily many arrays:

```
# Input: an array of arrays
def intersection:
  def i(y): ((unique + (y|unique)) | sort) as $sorted
  | reduce range(1; $sorted|length) as $i
       ([]; if $sorted[$i] == $sorted[$i-1] then . + [$sorted[$i]] else . end) ;
  reduce .[1:][] as $a (.[0]; i($a)) ;
```

Examples:

```
[ [1,2,4], [2,4,5], [4,5,6]] #=> [4]
[[]]                         #=> []
[]                           #=> null
```

Of course if `x` and `y` are already known to be sorted and/or unique, more efficient solutions are possible.  See in particular [Finite Sets of JSON Entities](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set#Finite_Sets_of_JSON_Entities)

Comment: seems unusually verbose for jq, but it certainly works which I can't say for any other solution I've tried. thank you

Comment: How do I use this function inside a .jq file? I don't understand why this doesn't work: `jq -f plugin-group.jq plugins.json`

https://gist.github.com/MagentaRuby/0ec5a4b7023b49d62e998c3925821863

Comment: `intersection` as defined here as arity 0.  Perhaps you meant something like: `.intersection = ([ .servers[].installed] | intersection)`

Answer (score 11):

NOTE: This solution assumes array1 has no duplicates.

### Simple Explanation

The complexity of all these answers obscures understanding the principle. That's unfortunate because the principle is simple:

> - array1 minus array2 returns:
> - everything that's left in array1
> - after removing everything that is in array2
> - (and discarding the rest of array2)

### Simple Demo

```bash
# From array1, subtract array2, leaving the remainder
$ jq --null-input '[1,2,3,4] - [2,4,6,8]'
[
  1,
  3
]

# Subtract the remainder from the original
$ jq --null-input '[1,2,3,4] - [1,3]'
[
  2,
  4
]

# Put it all together
$ jq --null-input '[1,2,3,4] - ([1,2,3,4] - [2,4,6,8])'
[
  2,
  4
]
```

### `comm` Demo

```js
def comm:
  (.[0] - (.[0] - .[1])) as $d |
    [.[0]-$d, .[1]-$d, $d]
;
```

With that understanding, I was able to imitate the behavior of [the *nix `comm` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html)

> With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one
> contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique
> to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

```bash
$ echo 'def comm: (.[0]-(.[0]-.[1])) as $d | [.[0]-$d,.[1]-$d, $d];' > comm.jq
$ echo '{"a":101, "b":102, "c":103, "d":104}'                        > 1.json
$ echo '{         "b":202,          "d":204, "f":206, "h":208}'      > 2.json

$ jq --slurp '.' 1.json 2.json
[
  {
    "a": 101,
    "b": 102,
    "c": 103,
    "d": 104
  },
  {
    "b": 202,
    "d": 204,
    "f": 206,
    "h": 208
  }
]

$ jq --slurp '[.[] | keys | sort]' 1.json 2.json
[
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "d",
    "f",
    "h"
  ]
]

$ jq --slurp 'include "comm"; [.[] | keys | sort] | comm' 1.json 2.json
[
  [
    "a",
    "c"
  ],
  [
    "f",
    "h"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "d"
  ]
]

$ jq --slurp 'include "comm"; [.[] | keys | sort] | comm[2]' 1.json 2.json
[
  "b",
  "d"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '[1,2,3,4] [2,4,6,8,10]' | jq --slurp '[.[0][] as $x | .[1][] | select($x == .)]'
[
  2,
  4
]
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer. Why does this work? What was the issue that you resolved? That makes it easier for OP and everyone in the future to understand their problem.

Comment: This solution requires both arrays to be passed to `jq` seperately. `jq` includes every element of the second array in its output, if it exists in the first array. I guess `jq` will linerarly (?) search the second array for each element of the first array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works by counting occurrences of elements in the arrays using **foreach**

```
[
  foreach ($X[], $Y[]) as $r (
    {}
  ; .[$r|tostring] += 1
  ; if .[$r|tostring] == 2 then $r else empty end
  )
]
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` then

```
jq -M -n -c --argjson X '[1,2,3,4]' --argjson Y '[2,4,6,8,10]' -f filter.jq
```

will produce

```
[2,4]
```

It assumes there are no duplicates in the initial arrays.  If that's not the case then it is easy to compensate with **unique**.  E.g.

```
[
  foreach (($X|unique)[], ($Y|unique)[]) as $r (
    {}
  ; .[$r|tostring] += 1
  ; if .[$r|tostring] == 2 then $r else empty end
  )
]
```

Comment: These are good solutions under certain circumstances, but will give incorrect answers if there are “collisions”, since (for example) both the number 1 and the string “1” are mapped to the latter value.