# Get intersection of arrays in JQ

Tags: arrays, json, jq, intersection

I'm new to jq,

and would like to get the intersection of two arrays (similar question BUT with **different approach**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364458/how-to-get-the-intersection-of-two-json-arrays-using-jq)).
I managed to get the union of two arrays and addition of two arrays:
i.e:

```
A=['a','b','e','c']
B=['g','a','t','c']
```

I have wrote:

```
echo '{"group_a":["A","B","C","ABC"],"group_b":["B","D"]}' | jq .group_a+.group_b
```

A+B = ['a','b','e','c','g','g','a','t','c']

```
echo '{"group_a":["A","B","C","ABC"],"group_b":["B","D"]}' | jq .group_a+.group_b | jq 'unique'
```

A U B = ['a','b','e','c','g','t']

but how do i now apply this simple logic:

```
intersection = unique((A+B) - (A U B))
```

i'm used to one liners, and I'd like this snippet to be readable and elegant for future use.
so how do i implement this in jq style?

any assistance will be helpful, Thank you all!

Comment: One of the tags is “set”, so please clarify whether we are to assume the inputs each have distinct elements, and similarly whether the result should have distinct elements; also, is there any requirement regarding the ordering of elements in the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the intersection of two JSON arrays using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364458/how-to-get-the-intersection-of-two-json-arrays-using-jq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming arrays do not contain duplicates (if they do, use `unique` to filter out duplicate results):

```sh
jq -cn '["a","b","e","c"] as $A | ["g","a","t","c"] as $B | $A - ($A - $B)'
```

```sh
echo '{ "group_a" : ["a","b","e","c"], "group_b" : ["g","a","t","c"] }' |
 jq -c '.group_a - (.group_a - .group_b)'
```

They both yield:

```
["a","c"]
```

Comment: WARNING: if $A contains duplicates, the results may not be what you want, e.g. `jq -cn '[1,2,1] as $A | [1] as $B  | $A - ($A - $B)'` #=> 
[1,1]

Comment: @peak I couldn't figure out a way to prevent this behaviour, could you?

Comment: @peak no no I mean what if `A = [1, 1, 1, 2]` and `B = [1, 1]`? Then `A ∩ B` should be `[1, 1]`, `unique` will produce `[1]`.

Comment: one of tags of the Q is “set”; your question evidently assumes a completely different semantics. I’d suggest you create a new SO Q.

Comment: In the jq FAQ and elsewhere, "jq 1.5+" means jq > 1.5 (i.e. NOT including jq 1.5).  Also, the filters you give will work with any extant jq (jq 1.3 or later) -- it's only the contraction of the command-line options that is relatively new.